# Getting statistics about builds statuts

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson, sonarqube

We use Hudson to build our application, and also Sonar to monitor the quality of our application.
CVS is our Source Code Management, but we will migrate in a few months to SVN.

Every week, we want to generate a quality report, where almost every metrics are retrieved from Sonar.
However, there are few others indicators that we would like to get (they should represent an average value for the past week):

- **Instability duration**: The average time needed for an unstable (or broken) build to be corrected;
- **% of broken builds**: The ratio `broken builds / total number of builds`;
- **% of unstable builds**: The ratio `unstable builds / total number of builds`;
- **% of commented commits**: Percentage of the CVS / SVN commits that have a comment (I know this is subjective, as you can just enter `Update`,  or anything else);

Note that for the second and third indicators, if I "only" get the raw values (i.e. # of builds, # of unstable builds and # of broken builds), this will be good too!

Is there a way (with a plugin for example) to get such metrics for the past week?
Also, is there a way to integrate them in Sonar directly?

Note that my builds are taking really too much space on disk, so we don't keep an history of our builds on Hudson.

*Parallel question*: Is there an Hudson plugin that keeps the statistics about builds history without keeping the Hudson history (which includes the artifacts)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build stability plugin should cover some points:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Build+Stability+Plugin

the scm activity plugin has some statistics for your checkins:
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/SCM+Activity+Plugin